# How do I delete/ignore error-producing results in an Excel named range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two ranges, RangeA and RangeB.  I would like to essentially do the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RangeA, 1/RangeB) / TotalItems
```

To get an average percentage. However, both of the ranges may have blank cells scattered through them, and I only want to include the corresponding cells from RangeA and RangeB when they are both not blank.

I have tried variations on the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RangeA<>"")*RangeA, 1/((RangeB<>"")*RangeB)) / TotalItems
```

But everything I've tried with `SUMPRODUCT` so far gives me a "#DIV/0!" error because it just ends up converting the blanks to zeros (note that using `RangeB<>0` produces the same reasult).

I could easily use the following custom function:

```vb
Function AvgPerc(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Single
    Dim ind As Integer, inVal As Single, outVal As Single, _
        Perc As Double, TotPerc As Double, valCount As Integer
    For ind = 1 To Range1.Rows.Count
        If IsNumeric(Range1.Item(ind, 1)) And IsNumeric(Range2.Item(ind, 1)) Then
            inVal = Range1.Item(ind, 1)
            outVal = Range2.Item(ind, 1)
            If inVal <> 0 And outVal <> 0 Then
                Perc = CDbl(outVal) / CDbl(inVal)
                TotPerc = TotPerc + Perc
                valCount = valCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ind
    If valCount = 0 Then
        AvgPerc = 0
    Else
        AvgPerc = TotPerc / valCount
    End If
End Function
```

However, this requires that the workbook be saved as a macro-enabled function and there will be people using this workbook that don't have macros enabled, and I don't want to have to ask them to enable macros for something as simple as this (in addition to that fact that it would cause confusion for people who start using the workbook later when I may not be available to explain what's going on).

Ultimately, I'm thinking that I might be able to use named ranges to do this without a macro, but I'm not sure how to delete the "#DIV/0!" results from the named range, and I really need to duplicate all the behavior in the custom function above.

## Example Data:

[image: Example Data]

Note that I would ideally be able to include the empty rows at the bottom of each column so people could add more data later.

Comment: This looks like it works: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(rangeA<>"")*rangeA, 1/(--(rangeB<>"")*rangeB))/ TotalItems`

Comment: Nope, gives me a "#DIV/0!" error.  I'll add an example to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you are using (`(RangeB<>"")*RangeB)`) converts empty values to `0`, which obviously gives the same error when it's a divisor too.

Two approach to use which work in this case:

- `=SUM(IFERROR(A2:A5/B2:B5,0))`
- `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5,IF(B2:B5=0,0,1/B2:B5))`

Both are array formulas, you need to finish them by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If *SUMPRODUCT()* gives problems, don't use it.

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="","",A2/B2)
```

and copy down.  then in another cell:

```
=AVERAGE(C2:C9999)
```

[image]

You can avoid the *helper column* with the *Array Formula*:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(A1:A100/B1:B100,""))/COUNT(B2:B100)
```

or

```
=AVERAGE((IFERROR(A2:A101/B2:B101,"")))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.